# How to know sent URL with Grails REST Client Builder Plugin RestBuilder.get()?

Tags: grails

Now, I'm developing Grails plugin for simplify use of Amazon PAAPI in Grails apps.

The goal of this plugin is provide convenient TagLib to doing Amazon PAAPI Operation like shown below.

```
<paapi:img idType="ISBN" itemId="4048668161" relationshipType="AuthorityTitle" size="medium" alt="alttext" />
```

The code will rendered like below.

```
<img src="http://mediumimageurl.jpg" alt="alttext" />
```

The Taglib need means connection to Amazon PAAPI. I choosed Grails REST Client Builder Plugin for that.

And I written below code. This is service method.

```
def itemLookup(
            String condition,
            String idType,
            String itemId,
            String merchantId,
            String offerPage,
            String relatedItemsPage,
            String relationshipType,
            String reviewPage,
            String reviewSort,
            String searchIndex,
            String tagPage,
            String tagsPerPage,
            String tagSort,
            String variationPage,
            ResponseGroup responseGroup) {
        def associateId = grailsApplication.config.grails.plugin.foo.amazonpaapi.associateId
        def paapiAccessKey = grailsApplication.config.grails.plugin.foo.amazonpaapi.paapiAccessKey
        def paapiSecretAccessKey = grailsApplication.config.grails.plugin.foo.amazonpaapi.paapiSecretAccessKey

        def rest = new RestBuilder()
        def resp = rest.get(
                "http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml",
                [
                    Service:'AWSECommerceService',
                    AWSAccessKeyId:paapiAccessKey,
                    AssociateTag:associateId,
                    Operation:'ItemLookup',
                    Condition:condition,
                    IdType:idType,
                    ItemId:itemId,
                    MerchantId:merchantId,
                    OfferPage:offerPage,
                    RelatedItemsPage:relatedItemsPage,
                    RelationshipType:relationshipType,
                    ReviewPage:reviewPage,
                    ReviewSort:reviewSort,
                    SearchIndex:searchIndex,
                    Tagage:tagPage,
                    TagsPerPage:tagsPerPage,
                    TagSort:tagSort,
                    VariationPage:variationPage,
                    ResponseGroup:responseGroup.getLabel()
                ]) {
            accept "application/xml"
        }
        return resp.xml
    }
```

The code is failed.

I got below result. It had entered `resp.txt`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html> <head> <title>400 Bad Request</title> </head> <body> <div align=center> <a href="http://www.amazon.com/"><img src="http://g-images.amazon.com/images/G/01/icons/amazon-logo.gif" width=140 height=30 alt="Amazon.com" border=0></a><br> </div> <h1>Bad Request</h1> <p>Parameter Operation is missing</p> </body> </html>
```

The problem is the thing you do not know why did this happen.

I want know, what URL sent to Amazon PAAPI from `RestBuilder.get()`. And I didn't find it.

Do you have any means to know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self solved.

Finally, I could not find means to know REST request url.

But, This error is solved. I found error message in request from Amazon

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html> <head> <title>400 Bad Request</title> </head> <body> <div align=center> <a href="http://www.amazon.com/"><img src="http://g-images.amazon.com/images/G/01/icons/amazon-logo.gif" width=140 height=30 alt="Amazon.com" border=0></a><br> </div> <h1>Bad Request</h1> <p>Parameter Operation is missing</p> </body> </html>

Parameter Operation is missing
```

I can resolve this error like below.

```
def resp = rest.get('http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?Operation={Operation}') {
        urlVariables Operation:'ItemLookup'
    }
```

Error seems to have been returned because there is no Operation parameters is essential.